# Angular: Cannot find namespace "Spotify" when using @types/spotify-web-playback-sdk

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spotify

I'm trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/spotify-web-playback-sdk in my angular project to type out the spotify player in one of my components. I Installed the types, as instructed...

```sh
npm install --save @types/spotify-web-playback-sdk
```

The Visual Studio code linter doesn't complain when I define this class variable and type it to a SpotifyPlayer ...

```js
// class variable
spotifyPlayer: Spotify.SpotifyPlayer;
```

But, when I go to build my code, I get this error...

```
ERROR in src/app/components/header/header.component.ts:32:18 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Spotify'.

32   spotifyPlayer: Spotify.SpotifyPlayer;
```

I'm using ...

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.0
Node: 10.15.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.0
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.0
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.0
@schematics/angular               9.1.0
@schematics/update                0.901.0
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the type definition [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/spotify-web-playback-sdk/index.d.ts) `spotify-web-playback-sdk` is `non-npm package`. 
As per the `Spotify` documentation [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/reference/#initializing-the-sdk), you would be adding the `JS bundle` in your `html` directly, which means this `Script` is not loaded as a `module`.

From [DefinitelyTyped](https://definitelytyped.org/)

> You may need to add a types reference if you're not using modules

You can add the below line to top of the file where you are using `Spotify namespace` and the error should disappear.

```
///  <reference types="@types/spotify-web-playback-sdk"/>
```

More information is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-types-) and [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-do-i-get-them). Whenever Spotify publishes a npm library prefer using that instead.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to import the namespace in every class
e.g. `import * as Spotify from 'Spotify'`